# How can I safely cast all data from a dataset populated by a SQL query as a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

Environment: ASP.net, vb.net, SQL Server

I'm retrieving a dataset from a stored procedure. I need to iterate over every column, grab the column name, and the value of the associated row... I'm storing the column names and values in a custom class.

The problem is, this is an end user situation, therefore I have absolutely no idea what SQL query they will use, or stored procedure for that matter.

When testing, I first ran into an issue that I've seen before, and it was easy to deal with...

Consider the following:

```
For Each column As DataColumn In DynamicQuery.Tables(0).Columns
  Dim columnName = column.ColumnName.ToString
  Dim value = CType(row(column.Columnname), String)

  ' Other code...
Next column
```

My first problem was running into a NULL value. I solved that with:

```
CType(If(IsDBNull(row(column.ColumnName)), String.Empty, row(column.ColumnName)), String)
```

I should also add that I want every single value to be converted to a string...

Then I ran into another problem, and that was testing a table which had a uniqueidentifier datatype.

I received the error:

```
Error converting 'GUID' to type 'String'
```

After a bit of reading, I see it's suggested to cast it into a GUID struct and then convert it to a string.

This leads to my main question.

Is there a simpler way to do this? Or should I be using:

```
Select Case column.DataType
```

On every single column iteration? If GUID is the only problem, I can deal with that one... Just waiting for a bunch of gotcha's down the road where yet another datatype causes an issue.

I suppose I'm looking for the appropriate method of defensive programming here. Again, no matter what the rows are that are returned into the dataset, every single column is read, and it's value, and everything needs to be either a string with a length, or an empty string. Apologies if I'm missing something plain and simple. C# or vb.net examples welcomed with a smile.

Comment: Have you thought about converting the output in to xml and then working with the xml instead of datatypes? You problem sounds like a challenge faced when developing reporting tools etc. If you think about reporting tools, most of them use xml.

Comment: Don't user `cType`, use `.ToSting()` instead.

Comment: @ZoharPeled That worked... Apparently I had tried that in all the wrong places, but placing it on the outer struct solved the problem. I suppose I'm letting the VS opt strict tell me too much of what to do. So this shouldn't become an issue with any datatype then?

Comment: Can anyone think of potential gotchas later on down the road?

Comment: @KosalaW Have not thought of this. Zohar's solution worked, but still looking for potential issues. WIll continue testing.

Comment: `CType` will try to cast the object to a string. That is not what `.ToString()` does. everything in the .Net framework will have a `.ToString()` method since it's derived from the most basic type - `Object`. However, not every object can be cast to a string, hence the exception you get for the guid.

Comment: Even with the `.ToString`, there will still be "Gotchas" like even though a binary field will not error, it will return something like "System.Btye[]", not data at all. I do what your asking in my programming regularly and have select cases that handle most types 1 way and specific types in specific ways. You just have to answer the question, "When data cannot be displayed as a string, how do I handle it?"